# Galois Theory.Subgroups of Galois Group

Tags: finite-groups, galois-theory, extension-field

How to List the subgroups of the Galois group in general.Im not interested in a specific Example but to make it easier. Supposes the galois group $G=Gal[Q(v,i):Q]$ $$v= \sqrt[4]{2}$$ I know how to find the possible Automorphisms (elements of the Galois group using the fact that is $a$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial its $(σa)$ is also a root (σ) is an automorphism)  but how do i list its subgroups.And how to know that i have listed them all and im not missing one?

Comment: I usually start by listing cyclic subgroups, then those generated by two elements et cetera. For groups of the size of your example that works well. If you get to bigger ones, then you need more techniques such as lumping conjugate subgroups together et cetera. TL; DR; ad hoc.

Comment: So no general Algorithm maybe using the Galois Corespodence or something? @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if we know the Galois group, this means we know its structure, in
this case it is a problem of group  theory  and not of Galois
theory, in this case we can, as indicated in the commentary, to
proceed by recognizing growing small subgroups while the group is
not already indicated in a classification list!!!. But it seems of
interest to you to use Galois theory for a Galois extension $ K /
\Bbb{Q} $ of degree $ n $; in this case, $K = \Bbb {Q} (\alpha)$,
a relevant information is that the group $Gal (K / \Bbb{Q})$ is a
group of order $n$ and is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup  of
$ S_{n}$. So

1) it is essential to have a primitive element $ \alpha $ of $K$
and know all its conjugates (the roots of $ irr (\alpha, K /
\Bbb{Q}) $, say $ \alpha = \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \cdot\cdot\cdot
\alpha_n$.

2) Learn the different divisors $ m $ of $ n $, to avoid trivial
subgroups keep only $ m \in \{2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, n-1 \} $.

3) form the different product $P= (X- \alpha_1) (\prod(X
-\alpha_{i_1}) \cdot\cdot\cdot (X -\alpha_{i_r}))$ with $ i_1 +
\cdot\cdot\cdot+ i_r = m-1$ and $i_j\neq i_l)$ search the field
generated by  $\Bbb{Q }$ and the coefficients of the polynomial $P$ in
3)

4) The Galois correspondence determines the subgroups as required.

For the given example: a primitive element is $ ^4\sqrt{2} + i$,
whose   conjugates  are in number $ 8$. Then the Galois group is of
order 8,   as we may see  as compositor of the real extension
$\Bbb{Q} (^4\sqrt{2})$ with $\Bbb{Q}(i)$. Moreover, he
identifies with a transitive subgroup of $ S_4 $,that is  a
2-Sylow of $S_4$, hence a   dihedral group generated by a 4-cycle
and a suitable  transposition. In this stage we can   lock to the
classification list (Group Theory) and determined the sub groups
of the dihedral group  $D_4 = \{e, a, a^2, a^3,b, ab, ab^2, ab^3
\} $, there are:

sub-groups of order 4: $ \{e, a, a^2, a^3  \}, \{e, a^2, b, ba^2
\} , \{e, a^2, ba, ba^3 \} $ of index 2, so normal in $D_4$.

sub-groups of order 2: $ \{e, a^2 \}, \{e, b \}, \{e, ba\},\{e,
ba^2\}, \{e,ba^3 \} $

others of order 1 and 8 are obvious.

so then if we need  to
determine the  intermediate extensions, the Galois correspondence
is applied after choosing well isomorphism between Galois group
and D_4.

Returning to the determination of these subgroup by Galois theory,
ie by means of the intermediate extensions of $K / \Bbb{Q}$. by
the method described above.

$\alpha = ^4\sqrt{2} + i $, start by $(\alpha-i)^4=2$ to arrive at
$irr(\alpha,\Bbb{Q})=X^8-16X^6+28X^2+1$, i know the roots:  $^4\sqrt{2}
+ i$ , $^4\sqrt{2} - i$,$-^4\sqrt{2} + i$ and $-^4\sqrt{2} + i$,
 $i^4\sqrt{2}
+ i$ , $i^4\sqrt{2} - i$,$-i^4\sqrt{2} + i$ and $-i^4\sqrt{2} + i$,
we form all product of two factors s.t (X-\alpha) divide the product
$(X-\alpha) (X-^4\sqrt{2} + i)
(X-\alpha) (X+^4\sqrt{2} - i)
(X-\alpha) (X+^4\sqrt{2} + i)
(X-\alpha) (iX-^4\sqrt{2} - i)
(X-\alpha) (iX-^4\sqrt{2} + i)
(X-\alpha) (X+i^4\sqrt{2} - i)
(X-\alpha) (X+i^4\sqrt{2} + i)$
and we form all product of four factors s.t (X-\alpha) divide the product

$(X-(\sqrt[4]{2}+i))(X-(\sqrt[4]{2}-i))=X^2-2X\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt{2}+1$

$(X-(\sqrt[4]{2}+i))(X-(-\sqrt[4]{2}-i))=X^2-\sqrt{2}-2i\sqrt[4]{2}+1$

$(X-(\sqrt[4]{2}+i))(X-(-\sqrt[4]{2}+i))=X^2-2iX-\sqrt{2}-1$

$(X-(\sqrt[4]{2}+i))(X-(i\sqrt[4]{2}-i))=X^2-iX\sqrt[4]{2}-X\sqrt[4]{2}+i%
\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt[4]{2}-\sqrt[4]{2}+1$

$(X-(\sqrt[4]{2}+i))(X-(i\sqrt[4]{2}+i))=X^2-iX\sqrt[4]{2}-2iX-X\sqrt[4]{2}+i%
\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt[4]{2}-\sqrt[4]{2}-1$

$(X-(\sqrt[4]{2}+i))(X-(-i\sqrt[4]{2}+i))=X^2+iX\sqrt[4]{2}-2iX-X\sqrt[4]{2}%
-i\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[4]{2}-1$

$(X-(\sqrt[4]{2}+i))(X-(-i\sqrt[4]{2}-i))=X^2+iX\sqrt[4]{2}-X\sqrt[4]{2}-i%
\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt[4]{2}+\sqrt[4]{2}+1$

we get the field generayed with this polynoms....

This is the first time I do this kind of calculation, it is tiring but we can always try.

Note that can be helpful is that the third polynomial generates the Galois extension $\Bbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$  which corresponds to the normal  sub group $\{e,a^2\}$ of $D_4$.
sorry  for my English and  Good luck

Comment: a Galois extension$ K/QK/Q $ of degree n; in this case, K=Q(α), a relevant information is that the group Gal(K/Q)  is a group of order n and is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of Sn. Not sure if this is true.

Comment: if P is on irreductible polynome over $\Bbb{Q}$ of degree n then the  Gaolis groupe of the small field over $\Bbb{Q}$ that contain all roots of P is  isomorphic to a transitve sub group of S_n.

Comment: How do you get the minimal polynomial of the primitive element?